# Passport.js Google strategy is not working with the React application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js, passport-local, passport-google-oauth

I am using passport.js google strategy for user authentication.
I am using OAUTH2.

When I launch my server and hit API through browser, it launches google signin page.
But when I hit API from react front-end, it never launches the googles signin page.

Please find below server code,

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(cors());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
        "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
    );
    res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "X-Requested-With,content-type"
    );
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


passport.use('google', new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: "clientID", -- my client id
    clientSecret: "clientSecret", -- my clientsecret
    callbackURL: "callbackURL" -- url
},
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        // User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
        //  console.log(err,user);
        //   return done(err, user);
        // });
        console.log(profile);
        return done(err, user);
    }
));

app.get('/googleauth',
    passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'] }));

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
})

passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
})

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log("REST server started on port 4000");
});
```

Axios call from react code,

```
  handleJGoogleLogin(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var current = this;
    axios.get('http://localhost:4000/googleauth')
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

I am stuck here, looking for some help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

The call from the react front-end is a bit different for the OAuth flow. Instead of the normal back-end call using `fetch` or `axios`
make the call like this:

```
window.open(`http://localhost:${backend-port}/auth/google`, "_self");
```

This command will make a get request to the back-end server AND open that google sign in window at the same time.
Took me a lot of time to figure this out but this is the way...

Comment: Consider upvoting the question as well so others can find the answer easily.

Answer (score 2):

I think that Passport thing only works on the server.  It is probably doing a redirect or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

A few things under your passport.use add in another parameter

```
   passport.use('google', new GoogleStrategy({
      clientID: "clientID", -- my client id
      clientSecret: "clientSecret", -- my clientsecret
      callbackURL: "callbackURL" -- url
      proxy: true
     },

   change:
          const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google- 
    auth').OAuth2Strategy;
     to: 
         const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;

      add in a second scope of profile
        app.get('/googleauth',
               passport.authenticate('google', { scope: 
               ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login','profile'] }));
```

Can you post your react code?